# Configure intellitrace for ignore a function

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-2013, intellitrace

In Visual Basic .Net
I use "**On error resume next**" and intellitrace collect many exceptions

i will like  ignore all exception in a specific function, it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, there are a number of options for including fewer or more events at Debug -> IntelliTrace -> Open IntelliTrace Settings.

There is an options pane that allows you to control which modules are profiled, for example. This could let you exclude an entire assembly if you have no interest in any of its behavior.

You may also be using the stand-alone collector or the version included in Microsoft Test Manager.

All of these techniques run IntelliTrace by passing it a collection plan, which might give you some options you can't find in the UI. Visual Studio 2013 uses the configuration at %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\en

There is no way to prevent exceptions bubbling up through a particular method from being collected.